# How do add a ratio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm wanting to add a ratio to my vote count. Currently I'm making a music module. The music commands such as pause, skip, volume and so on are based on reactions (emojis) given by a user.

Currently to skip a song requires 5 reactions. One of the issues raised that sometimes there is less than five listening to music in a voice channel at one time and therefore cannot skip the song.

So I'm needing to implement ratio of some kind that say if 2 members are in a voice channel then 2 skips will skip that song for example.  I'm a bit unsure how to implement it but I gave it a go.

More specifically I'm looking at this line:

```
if control == 'skip':
        skip = await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
        if react.count >= 5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
            vc.stop()
            await channel.send('**Skipping song...**', delete_after=5)
```

Here is the full code I'm working with:

````
if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
    load_opus_lib()


ytdlopts = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
'restrictfilenames': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'nocheckcertificate': True,
'ignoreerrors': False,
'logtostderr': False,
'quiet': True,
'no_warnings': True,
'default_search': 'auto',
'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpegopts = {
    'before_options': '-nostdin -preset ultrafast',
    'options': '-vn -threads 1'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    """Custom Exception class for connection errors."""


class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
    super().__init__(source)
    self.requester = requester

    self.title = data.get('title')

    if self.title is None:
        self.title = "No title available"

    self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')
    self.thumbnail = data.get('thumbnail')

    if self.thumbnail is None:
        self.thumbnail = "http://ppc.tools/wp-content/themes/ppctools/img/no-thumbnail.jpg"

    self.duration = data.get('duration')

    if self.duration is None:
        self.duration = 0

    self.uploader = data.get('uploader')

    if self.uploader is None:
        self.uploader = "Unkown"

    # YTDL info dicts (data) have other useful information you might want
    # https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

def __getitem__(self, item: str):
    """Allows us to access attributes similar to a dict.

    This is only useful when you are NOT downloading.
    """
    return self.__getattribute__(item)

@classmethod
async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]

    await ctx.send(f':notes: **{data["title"]} added to the queue.**')

    if download:
        source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    else:
        return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

@classmethod
async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
    """Used for preparing a stream, instead of downloading.

    Since Youtube Streaming links expire."""
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    requester = data['requester']

    to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)

class MusicPlayer:
"""A class which is assigned to each guild using the bot for Music.

This class implements a queue and loop, which allows for different guilds to listen to different playlists
simultaneously.

When the bot disconnects from the Voice it's instance will be destroyed.
"""

__slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_ctxs', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume', 'buttons', 'music', 'music_controller', 'restmode')

def __init__(self, ctx):

    self.buttons = {'⏯': 'rp',
                    '⏭': 'skip',
                    '➕': 'vol_up',
                    '➖': 'vol_down',
                    '': 'thumbnail',
                    '⏹': 'stop',
                    'ℹ': 'queue',
                    '❔': 'tutorial'}

    self.bot = ctx.bot
    self._guild = ctx.guild
    self._ctxs = ctx
    self._channel = ctx.channel
    self._cog = ctx.cog

    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
    self.next = asyncio.Event()

    self.np = None
    self.volume = .5
    self.current = None
    self.music_controller = None

    ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

async def buttons_controller(self, guild, current, source, channel, context):
    vc = guild.voice_client
    vctwo = context.voice_client

    for react in self.buttons:
        await current.add_reaction(str(react))

    def check(r, u):
        if not current:
            return False
        elif str(r) not in self.buttons.keys():
            return False
        elif u.id == self.bot.user.id or r.message.id != current.id:
            return False
        elif u not in vc.channel.members:
            return False
        elif u.bot:
            return False
        return True

    while current:
        if vc is None:
            return False

        react, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        control = self.buttons.get(str(react))

        if control == 'rp':
            if vc.is_paused():
                vc.resume()
            else:
                vc.pause()
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'skip':
            skip = await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
            if react.count >= 5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
                vc.stop()
                await channel.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)


        if control == 'stop':
            mods = get(guild.roles, name="Mods")
            for member in list(guild.members):
                if mods in member.roles:
                    await context.invoke(self.bot.get_command("stop"))
                    return
            else:
                await channel.send(':raised_hand:  **Only a mod can stop and clear the queue. Try skipping the song instead.**', delete_after=5)
                await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_up':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume += 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'vol_down':
            player = self._cog.get_player(context)
            vctwo.source.volume -= 2.5
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'thumbnail':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).set_image(url=source.thumbnail).set_footer(text=f"Requested By: {source.requester} | Video Thumbnail: {source.title}", icon_url=source.requester.avatar_url), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'tutorial':
            await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E).add_field(name="How to use the music controller?", value="⏯ - Pause\n⏭ - Skip\n➕ - Increase Volume\n➖ - Increase Volume\n - Get Thumbnail\n⏹ - Stop & Leave\nℹ - Queue\n❔ - Display help for music controls"), delete_after=10)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)

        if control == 'queue':
            await self._cog.queue_info(context)
            await current.remove_reaction(react, user)


async def player_loop(self):
    """Our main player loop."""
    await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

    while not self.bot.is_closed():
        self.next.clear()

        try:
            async with timeout(3500):
                source = await self.queue.get()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return self.destroy(self._guild)

        if not isinstance(source, YTDLSource):
            # Source was probably a stream (not downloaded)
            # So we should regather to prevent stream expiration
            try:
                source = await YTDLSource.regather_stream(source, loop=self.bot.loop)
            except Exception as e:
                await self._channel.send(f'An error occured!.\n'
                                         f'```css\n[{e}]\n```')
                continue

        source.volume = self.volume
        self.current = source
        try:
            self._guild.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda _: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.next.set))
        except Exception:
            continue
        embednps = discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E)
        embednps.add_field(name="Currently Playing:", value=f"```fix\n{source.title}```", inline=False)
        embednps.add_field(name="Requested By:", value=f"**{source.requester}**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Source:", value=f"**[URL]({source.web_url})**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Uploader:", value=f"**{source.uploader}**", inline=True)
        embednps.add_field(name="Duration:", value=f"**{datetime.timedelta(seconds=source.duration)}**", inline=True)
        embednps.set_thumbnail(url=source.thumbnail)
        self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embednps)

        self.music_controller = self.bot.loop.create_task(self.buttons_controller(self._guild, self.np, source, self._channel, self._ctxs))
        await self.next.wait()

        # Make sure the FFmpeg process is cleaned up.
        source.cleanup()
        self.current = None

        try:
            # We are no longer playing this song...
            await self.np.delete()
            self.music_controller.cancel()
        except Exception:
            pass

def destroy(self, guild):
    """Disconnect and cleanup the player."""
    return self.bot.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))

class Music:
"""Music cog for UKGBot."""

__slots__ = ('bot', 'players', 'musictwo', 'music_controller')

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.players = {}

async def cleanup(self, guild):
    try:
        await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        del self.players[guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        pass

async def __local_check(self, ctx):
    """A local check which applies to all commands in this cog."""
    if not ctx.guild:
        raise commands.NoPrivateMessage
    return True

async def cleanup(self, guild):
    try:
        await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        del self.players[guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        pass

async def __error(self, ctx, error):
    """A local error handler for all errors arising from commands in this cog."""
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        try:
            return await ctx.send(':notes: Command cannot be used in DM.')
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
    elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
        await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel first!")

    print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

def get_player(self, ctx):
    """Retrieve the guild player, or generate one."""
    try:
        player = self.players[ctx.guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        player = MusicPlayer(ctx)
        self.players[ctx.guild.id] = player

    return player

@commands.command(name='stop', aliases=[ 'l', 'disconnect'])
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def disconnect_(self, ctx):
    """Stops and leaves the voice channel."""

    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    except AttributeError:
        await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    if not ctx.guild.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send(':notes: I\'m not connected to the voice channel.', delete_after=20)

    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send(':wave: Stopped and left the channel.', delete_after=20)



@commands.command(name='reconnect', aliases=['rc'])
async def reconnect_(self, ctx):
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    if ctx.guild.voice_client:
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()

    await channel.connect()



@commands.command(name='connect', aliases=['join','summon'])
async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    """connectss to a voice channel."""  
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    await channel.connect()

@commands.command(name='skip', aliases=['sk'])
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def skip_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    """Skips a song (Mods)."""  
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)

    ctx.guild.voice_client.stop()
    await ctx.send(':track_next: **Skipping...**', delete_after=5)




@commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing', 'p'])
async def play_(self, ctx, *, search: str):
    """searches for and plays a song."""

    await ctx.trigger_typing()

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if not vc:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send(":notes: You are not connected to a voice channel.", delete_after=20)


    player = self.get_player(ctx)

    # If download is False, source will be a dict which will be used later to regather the stream.
    # If download is True, source will be a discord.FFmpegPCMAudio with a VolumeTransformer.
    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)
    await player.queue.put(source)



@commands.command(name='playing', aliases=['np', 'current', 'currentsong', 'now_playing'])
async def now_playing_(self, ctx):
    """Shows the current song playing."""

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
        return await ctx.send("I'm not connected to a voice channel..", delete_after=20)

    elif ctx.author not in ctx.guild.voice_client.channel.members:
        return await ctx.send("You need to be in the voice channel first!", delete_after=20)

    player = self.get_player(ctx)
    if not player.current:
        return await ctx.send("There's nothing currently playing.", delete_after=20)

    try:
        # Remove our previous now_playing message.
        await player.np.delete()
    except discord.HTTPException:
        pass

    embednp = discord.Embed(color=0x17FD6E)
    embednp.add_field(name="Currently Playing:", value=f"```fix\n{vc.source.title}```", inline=False)
    embednp.add_field(name="Requested By:", value=f"**{vc.source.requester}**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Source:", value=f"**[URL]({vc.source.web_url})**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Uploader:", value=f"**{vc.source.uploader}**", inline=True)
    embednp.add_field(name="Duration:", value=f"**{datetime.timedelta(seconds=vc.source.duration)}**", inline=True)
    embednp.set_thumbnail(url=f"{vc.source.thumbnail}")
    player.np = await ctx.send(embed=embednp)
    self.music_controller = self.bot.loop.create_task(MusicPlayer(ctx).buttons_controller(ctx.guild, player.np, vc.source, ctx.channel, ctx))

async def queue_info(self, ctx):
    player = self.get_player(ctx)
    if player.queue.empty():
        return await ctx.send('**:notes: No songs currently queued.**', delete_after=5)

    upcoming = list(itertools.islice(player.queue._queue, 0, 5))

    fmt = '\n'.join(f'**`{_["title"]}`**' for _ in upcoming)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{len(upcoming)} songs queued.', description=fmt, color=0x17FD6E)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
````

If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do something like this

```
if control == 'skip':
  skip = await channel.send(f':poop: **{user.name}** voted to skip **{source.title}**. **{react.count}/5** voted.', delete_after=8)
  try:
    ratio = react.count / len(ctx.author.voice.channel.members)
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
  if ratio  >= .5: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
    vc.stop()
    await channel.send('**Skipping song...**', delete_after=5)
```

where it would only skip the song if more than or exactly half of the people in the voice channel voted to skip
You could adjust the ratio you want later on

Comment: Unfortunately this is causing this reactions to stop working when a the skip reaction is made.

Comment: "would only skip the song if more than or exactly half of the people in the voice channel voted to skip" that means more? I was looking for if 2 members are in voice chat then 2 votes would skip and if 3 then 3 votes and 4 and 5 and so on. Sorry I'm a little confused by this. I tried this but this seems to cause the reactions to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to allow all members to vote together when there are less than five is to use something like:

```python
votes_needed_to_skip = min(current_listener_count, 5)
if react.count >= votes_needed_to_skip: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
```

If you want 3/4 of the people or five people, whichever comes first, to be able to skip it (be aware that 3/4 of six people is four people with this method, so only four votes are needed with six total people even though there are more than five people):

```python
votes_needed_to_skip = min(current_listener_count*3//4, 5)
if react.count >= votes_needed_to_skip: # bot counts as 1 reaction.
```